# a software for finding which processes use COM Ports, in windows

Tags: ports

I need a program to show which programs or processes use the COM ports.
I found some programs that monitor the COM ports such as Device Monitoring studio, .... but this program does not show which programs use the port.

Do you know a software for my problem?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Process Explorer.

Search for "serial" using ctrl-f.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx